# Rails User cannot sign up is email already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Hello I am trying to fix up my user sign up so if a user is already registered with the site with the same email, they cannot sign up. So far this is the code in my controller I am trying to implement.

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    unless User.exists?(:email => params[:email])

    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        @user.cart = Cart.create
        @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

I figured that in the users controller I would have an unless conditional so if a user already exists it would prevent that user from signing up and just render the new page again. However the user is still able to sign up. Any ideas on how to do this properly would really help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of validating this in your controller, move the validation to the User model, and add this line:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```